# getting sprites to work with three.js and different camera types

Tags: three.js

I've got a question about getting sprites to work with three.js using perspective and orthogonal cameras.

I have a building being rendered in one scene. At one location in the scene all of the levels are stacked on top of each other to give a 3D view of the building and an orthogonal camera is being used to view it. In another part of the scene, I have just the selected level of the building being shown and a perspective camera is being used. The screen is divided between the two views. The idea being the user selects a level from the building view and a more detailed map of that selected level is shown on the other part of the screen.

I played around with sprites for a little bit and as far as I understand it; if the sprite is being viewed with a perspective camera then the sprite's scale property is actual it's size property and if a sprite is being viewed with an orthogonal camera the scale property scales the sprite according to the view port.

I placed the sprite where both cameras can see it and this seems to be the case. If I scale the sprite by 0.5, then the sprite takes up half the orthogonal camera's view port and I can't see it with the perspective camera (presumably because for it, the sprite is 0.5px x 0.5px and is either rounded to 0px (not rendered, or 1px, effectively invisible). If I scale the sprite by say 50, the the perspective camera can see it (presumably because it's a 50px x 50px square) and the orthogonal camera is over taken by the sprite (presumably because it's being scaled by 50 times the view port).

Is my understanding correct?

I ask because in the scene I'm rendering, the building and detailed areas are ~1000 units apart on the x-axis. If I place a sprite somewhere on the detail map I need it to be ~35x35 pixels and when I do this it works fine for the detail view but building view is overtaken. I played with the numbers and it seems that if I scale the sprite by 4, it starts to show up on my building view, even though there's a 1000 unit distance between the views and the sprite isn't visible with the perspective camera.

So. If my understanding is correct then I need to either use separate scenes; have a much bigger gap between views; use the same camera type for both views; or not use sprites.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two different ways you can use sprites, either with 2D screen coordinates or 3D scene coordinates.  Perhaps scene coordinates are what you need? For examples of both, check out the example at:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprites.html

and in particular, when you zoom in and zoom out in that demo, notice that the sprites in-scene will change size, while the others do not.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using the sprites to show 'points of interest' so I'm using 3D world coordinates rather than using them as a HUD (2D screen coordinates). It's not so much of a question of how to use sprites as it is on how they 'interact' with the two different camera systems since the scale property seems to behave differently depending on what camera system is viewing the sprite.

Comment: IE: Alter the example shown at: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Viewports-Dual.html so that the cube is a sprite and one of the views is using an orthogonal camera and try to get the sprite to appear the same size on both views